# Instantiate a generic type having constructor using reflection C#

Tags: c#, reflection, instantiation

I am building a Validation Framework which, on the basis of rules stored in a JSON file.

```
"Url": "weatherforecast",
"Verb": "POST",
"Parameters": [
  {
    "Name": "AcctNo",
    "VariableType": "System.Int32",
    "ValidationRules": {
      "MinValue": 2
      
    }]
}
```

This means that Acctno of type Int32 would need to have a minimum value of 2.

This is minValue is represented by a generic class.

```
public class MinValue<T> : IValidationRule<T>
{
    public MinValue(T value)
    {

    }

    public List<T> GetPositiveValidationCases()
    {
        return new List<T>();
    }
}
```

The method would return test cases for me to try out combinations .

Now, when trying to instantiate using reflection, I tried this

```
Type type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType("ValidationFramework.ValidationRules.MinValue");
Type d1 = Type.GetType(validationRule.Key.ToString());
var makeme = MakeGenericType(d1, parameter.ParameterType);
Object[] args = { "value", Convert.ChangeType(validationRule.Value, parameter.ParameterType) };
Object o = Activator.CreateInstance(d1, args);
```

However the type in first line is coming up as null, I need to instantiate stuff using reflection.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The name of that type is ``MinValue`1``.

Comment: Tried that, still didnt work :(

Comment: So, is there a type of that name in the executing assambly? You did not show us... a [mcve] might help.

Comment: The full name would include the namespace, of course, but yeah, without an MRE this is going to be hard. ``Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType("MyNamespace.MinValue`1")`` will work if it's defined in the current assembly. Of course `Type.GetType(validationRule.Key...)` will still not work, because `MinValue` is not a type name.